# Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030

Tags: sparql, semantics, semantic-web, virtuoso

why is showing this error, i see in the sparql query is correct, i don't see any mistake in prefix.

```
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> 
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?country_name ?population 
WHERE { ?country rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country;
rdfs:label ?country_name ; 
prop:populationEstimate ?population . 
FILTER (?population > 2334456) . 
FILTER ( lang(?country_name) = 'en')}
```

Error:
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 1: Missing  in PREFIX declaration at '<' before 'http:'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 define input:default-graph-uri http://dbpedia.org  PREFIX rdfs:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you've shown us might not be the same as the query you're actually running.  First, the fact that the error message says "line 1" makes me wonder whether you've  actually got the query run all onto one  line.  That can make it easy to get typo problems.

When I put your query into [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html), I do get a syntax error, because there's no prefix defined for **rdf:**.  This is an error:

> Line 7, column 18: Unresolved prefixed name: rdf:type

That said, the interactive web interface to the DBpedia endpoint includes some predefined namespace prefixes, and if you paste the query from the question into [the web interface](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), it works just fine:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> 
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?country_name ?population 
WHERE { ?country rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country;
rdfs:label ?country_name ; 
prop:populationEstimate ?population . 
FILTER (?population > 2334456) . 
FILTER ( lang(?country_name) = 'en')}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3Fpopulation%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3ACountry%3B%0D%0Ardfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3B%20%0D%0Aprop%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3Fpopulation%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%20%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%202334456%29%20.%20%0D%0AFILTER%20%28%20lang%28%3Fcountry_name%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I like to use the [prefixes that DBpedia defines](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl), since it makes copying and pasting easier, so  I've used the prefix **dbpprop:** instead of **prop:**.  I've also used **langMatches** instead of **lang(…) = …**, because it works with regional variants of languages, whereas the latter won't.  I ended up with this query:

```sql
select ?country_name ?population where {
  ?country rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country ;
           rdfs:label ?country_name ; 
           dbpprop:populationEstimate ?population . 
  filter (?population > 2334456) 
  filter langMatches(lang(?country_name),'en')
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3Fpopulation%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdf%3Atype%20dbpedia-owl%3ACountry%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_name%20%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpprop%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3Fpopulation%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%202334456%29%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fcountry_name%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: thanks, this is the same query i am running, i am running in link with json when i put in browser, All of this "<" in Prefix change into 3C in the browser, i don't know why

Comment: Second sparql query its working, but i have problem with prefix in browser, this is what is showing in browser,
http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/> PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ?place WHERE { ?place rdf:type yago:%@ . ?place rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country } &format=application/json&timeout=100000&debug=on

When i excute its call same error

Comment: @RrezartA.Prebreza Code doesn't copy well in comments. Reread your previous comment;  I doubt that it's what you wanted to show me, as it's definitely not a well formed SPARQL query.